# How could I remove newlines from all quoted pieces of text in a file?

Tags: python, bash, csv

I have exported a CSV file from a database.  Certain fields are longer text chunks, and can contain newlines.  What would be the simplest way of removing only newlines from this file that are inside double quotes, but preserving all others?

I don't care if it uses a Bash command line one liner or a simple script as long as it works.

For example,

```
"Value1", "Value2", "This is a longer piece
    of text with
    newlines in it.", "Value3"
"Value4", "Value5", "Another value", "value6"
```

The newlines inside of the longer piece of text should be removed, but not the newline separating the two rows.

Comment: Could the values contain escaped quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python:

```
import csv
with open("input.csv", newline="") as input, \
        open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    for record in csv.reader(input):
        w.writerow(tuple(s.remove("\n") for s in record))
```

Comment: @MarkByers: Thanks.  I think this handles quoting more [configurably](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.doublequote) than easily possible with regular expressions.

Comment: I get "Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)" on line 4

Comment: replace rb by rt to open the file as text instead of binary. See my answer for the corrected version.

Comment: @Nereis This answer was written for Python 2, but I guess that's not longer relevant. I'll change it to Python 3 – thanks for the heads-up! Note that the encoding defaults to UTF-8, so you don't need to explicitly specify that, and both the input file and the output file should be opened with `newline=""` to handle newlines in quoted values correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution in Python:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'".*?"', re.DOTALL)
print pattern.sub(lambda x: x.group().replace('\n', ''), text)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Fbp96)

Answer (score 2):

This is very simplistic but might work for you:

```
# cat <<\! | sed ':a;/"$/{P;D};N;s/\n//g;ba'                            
> "Value1", "Value2", "This is a longer piece
>     of text with
>     newlines in it.", "Value3"
> "Value4", "Value5", "Another value", "value6"
> !
"Value1", "Value2", "This is a longer piece    of text with    newlines in it.", "Value3"
"Value4", "Value5", "Another value", "value6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the adjustment of [Sven's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219584/1511277) for Python 3 on Windows

```
with open(src, "rt") as input, open(dest, "wt", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as output:
w = csv.writer(output)
for record in csv.reader(input):
    w.writerow(tuple(s.replace('\n', '') for s in record))
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a `perl` one-liner

```bash
perl -pe 's/[^"]\n//' input.csv
```

#### output

```bash
"Value1", "Value2", "This is a longer piec    of text wit    newlines in it.", "Value3"
"Value4", "Value5", "Another value", "value6"
```

and not to forget reformat spaces

```bash
perl -pe 's/[^"]\n//; s/\s+/ /' input.csv
```

#### output

```bash
"Value1", "Value2", "This is a longer piec of text wit newlines in it.", "Value3"
"Value4", "Value5", "Another value", "value6"
```