# Why the output is not meeting my code condition?

Tags: python, regex

I have this piece of code here to adjust some linebreaks when my qualifier is not even.

```
linebreak = ''
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        line1 = line.strip()

        if len(linebreak) > 0:
            linebreak = linebreak + ' ' + line1
            res = re.sub(r'"[^"]+"', lambda m: m.group(0).replace("\n", ""), linebreak)
            if (Counter(linebreak)['"'] % 2) == 0:
                linebreak = ''
                print(res)                  
        
        if (Counter(line1)['"'] % 2) != 0:
            nextline = next(f, None).strip()            
            linebreak = line1 + ' ' + nextline
            res = re.sub(r'"[^"]+"', lambda m: m.group(0).replace("\n", ""), linebreak)
            
            if (Counter(linebreak)['"'] % 2) == 0:
                linebreak = ''
                print(res)                
                
        if (Counter(line1)['"'] % 2) == 0: 
            print(line1)
```

The problem is, the last line from my file is not printing out, even though it matches the last **if condition**.

File:

```
"content of row 1 abcde" | abcde
abcde | "content of row 2
 continues here"
content of row 3 | abcde
"content of row 4 
 continues here" | "Test
ing"
Teste1
```

Output:

```
"content of row 1 abcde" | abcde
abcde | "content of row 2 continues here"
content of row 3 | abcde
"content of row 4 continues here" | "Test ing"
```

Expected:

```
"content of row 1 abcde" | abcde
abcde | "content of row 2 continues here"
content of row 3 | abcde
"content of row 4 continues here" | "Test ing"
Teste1
```

Also, I'd appreciate any easier way to do this linebreak fix!

Edit:
This line do the job on GNU Linux, but I'd like to keep it on Python

```
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/[\r\n]+/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' file > file.txt
```

Comment: Which do you thing this last line fullfill the condition ? like you have 3 conditions, where it should go ?

Comment: @Nilesh the last one. Edited to make it clear.

Comment: Maybe have a look and the Python answer in [How could I remove newlines from all quoted pieces of text in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219502/how-could-i-remove-newlines-from-all-quoted-pieces-of-text-in-a-file)

Comment: @MDR Two problems with this solution: (1) I have to read line by line since my file has over 100gb and (2) only some of my data has qualifiers between delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an even number of `"`, you should continue with next lines, you don't have to test the other `ifs`. So, you need a `continue` when the line is complete.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

linebreak = ''
path = "in.txt"
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        line1 = line.strip()        

        if len(linebreak) > 0:            
            linebreak = linebreak + ' ' + line1
            res = re.sub(r'"[^"]+"', lambda m: m.group(0).replace("\n", ""), linebreak)
            if (Counter(linebreak)['"'] % 2) == 0:
                linebreak = ''
                print(res)
                continue  ### ADDED   LINE ###
        
        if (Counter(line1)['"'] % 2) != 0:            
            nextline = next(f, None).strip()            
            linebreak = line1 + ' ' + nextline
            res = re.sub(r'"[^"]+"', lambda m: m.group(0).replace("\n", ""), linebreak)
            
            if (Counter(linebreak)['"'] % 2) == 0:
                linebreak = ''
                print(res)               
                
        if (Counter(line1)['"'] % 2) == 0: 
            print(line1)
```